# SMTP Priority Specification

Tags: php, email, smtp, swiftmailer, rfc822

This is not a matter of how to set the priority of an email, but rather a matter of why the values are what they are, and where those are specified.

Pretty much every SMTP Library that I've seen states that there's 5 priorities:

- 1: Highest
- 2: High
- 3: Normal
- 4: Low
- 5: Lowest

However, none of them actually cite their sources, which leaves me to wonder if this is just something globally understood, or if there's an actual specification.

Could someone please explain to me when these priorities where first enforced, and properly specified? I tried looking through a bunch of RFC stuff, but I all I found was how to handle message priorities, not what the values were.

Personally, I'm implementing the SwiftMailer PHP library. You can find it's priority settings [here](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMessage.php#L443-474). However, as stated, there is no reference to back its claim.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6710#section-5

Comment: That's definitely helpful, but now I'm curious as to why the SMTP services only support 1-5. I'd understand if a single service did this, and that complies with the RFC, but all of them? There has to be additional reasoning behind this.

Comment: 19 levels of priority seems like overkill too, plus being a weird number. a power-of-two I'd understand, but 19 is... odd.

Comment: Well, RFC specifies -9 to 9, which makes 19 when you include zero. They probably picked 9 because of our human tendencies to think in base 10. While I agree that 5 is better, I'd like to know who originally made that call. Even software like Outlook only uses two or three of the "five" options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6710.html#page-4

... when relaying the message to the next hop or delivering ...

... an SMTP client that has more than one email to
send at a given time sends those with a higher priority before those
with a lower one.  Additionally, the retry interval and/or default
timeout before a non-delivery report is generated MAY be lower (more
aggressive) for messages of higher priority.
...

Delivery time constraints...

Priority of email was originally related to hosts that were not always connected. This caused an undeliverable after xx attempts reply to the originator to be sent after varying number of days depending on priority.